# Issue with asp-validation-for when used in a loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I am having an issue with the asp-validation-for on a span element in the code below.

```
 <div class="form-group">
                @if (Model.Property.Options.ElementAt(i).OptionTypeId == PropertyOptionType.CheckBox)
                {
                    var ItemChecked = (Model.Property.Options.ElementAt(i).OptionValue == "on") ? " checked" : "";
                    <text><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="Options[@i].Code" id="Options[@i].Code" @ItemChecked data-val="false" />
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="Options[@i].Value">&nbsp;@(Model.Property.Options.ElementAt(i).OptionValue)</label></text>
                }
                else if (Model.Property.Options.ElementAt(i).OptionTypeId == PropertyOptionType.List)
                {
                    <label class="control-label">
                        @Model.Property.Options.ElementAt(i).OptionValue
                    </label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="Options[@i].Code"></select>
                }
                <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Options.@(i).Code"></span>
```

When it is rendered in HTML it comes out as

```
<span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Options.[3].Code"></span>
```

But no validation error messages ever land in the span. They are picked up in a page level validation summary when set to all so the unobtrusive code is all working correctly but the ID of the span is being broken by the square brackets.

Any ideas?
Thanks
Mark

Comment: Its a typo - you have an extra `.` (dot) in `data-valmsg-for="Options.[3].Code"` - it needs to be `data-valmsg-for="Options[3].Code"` (and why in the world are you generating your html manually like that instead of strongly binding to your model?)

Answer (score 0):

To display [Validation Summary](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-validationsummary), you need to include:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false/*excludePropertyErrors?*/, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

To display field specific error message, you need to use `ValidationMessageFor`:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StudentName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StudentName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

[See this tutorial](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/implement-validation-in-asp.net-mvc)

Don't manually generate the validation span, html helpers will do that for you... you would need something like this:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Property.Options.Count(); i++)
{
    /* this one generates the input */
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Property.Options[i], new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

    /* this one generates the validation message */
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Property.Options[i], "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
}
```

Comment: Hi there - this isn't the issue I it results in a span `<span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Code"></span>` and completely loses the context of the data-valmsg-for element!

Comment: The last span in the original code post. This is inside a for loop that is causing the problem!

Comment: The HTML helpers also don't generate the correct decoration on the name and id - they strip it out to just 'Options'